# How do I Copy and Past date text from a range of filtered cells, into a CSV?

Tags: excel, vba, text, copy, paste

I'm trying to copy a range of filtered, date formatted cells into a CSV file. I want the text of the date, not the date code.

This is what I have so far. It gets the date code, but I want the text.

```
.Range.Columns(EmployeeEffectiveDateCol).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    TemplateSheet.Range("G2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I don't think an answer to this exists! Haha. I can't find a way to grab the TEXT of a range of filtered cells, BUT I've come up with a work around that will do.

The CSV file is open in Excel while I'm populating it. At this time the cells can be formatted, but the formatting is lost when the file is closed. So, I need to reset the cells before I save and close. For this I've found a loop which I can call right after the copy/pasting is done:

```
TemplateSheet.Range("G2:G500").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
For Each Cell In TemplateSheet.Range("G2:G500")
  Cell.Value = Cell.Text
Next Cell
```

This of course requires a Dim Cell As Range at the top of the code. It's not as elegant a solution as I'd hoped, but I just need the job done now! Haha. It works fairly quickly too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) to .PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

It will not only paste values but also replicate cell formats (in this case - dates).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, because I'm pasting into a CSV, not an xlsx, the formats will go as soon as the sheet is closed. The next time it opens the cell displays the date code in a general formatted cell. I need to paste in the date as a string, which means I need to copy it as a string.